# WPF Combobox Background for Different Selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, styles

I have Combobox with Just 3 item : Planing, Progress and Done,

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Planing"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Progress"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Done"/>
</ComboBox>
```

How Can i Change Background Color Of ComboBox (which is by defult Gradiant) Depend on Which Item is Selected.

For Example : purple for Planing, blue for Progress and Green for Done.

Note: I mean ComboBox Background, not ComboBox Items List.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1) Using selectionChanged event

You could set it up in the `comboBox_SelectionChanged` event

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Planning")
    {
        comboBox.Background = Brushes.Purple;
    }
    else if (comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Progress")
    {
        comboBox.Background = Brushes.Blue;
    }
    else if (comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Done")
    {
        comboBox.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }
}
```

The `comboBox_SelectionChanged` event will be called each time the selected value in the combobox is changed. Inside it you can simply verify the value of the selected item and apply the color you want.

This would be the xaml of the `Combobox`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

---

### 2) Using DataTriggers in XAML

It can also be done through the xaml by setting up multiple `DataTrigger` on the `Style.Triggers` like this

```
<ComboBox x:Name="mycombobox">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=mycombobox}" Value="Planning">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=mycombobox}" Value="Progress">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=mycombobox}" Value="Done">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Planning"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Progress"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Done"/>
</ComboBox>
```

[More information on DataTriggers:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a trigger that applies property values or performs actions when the bound data meets a specified condition.

Comment: Thanks, but Is there a way to do through the xaml?

Comment: @High I added how to do it with the xml.

Comment: i,m new in wpf and it was very valuable for me, thanks

Comment: XAML doesn't seem to work in VisualStudio 2019 on a Windows 10 machine. The code works, but it doesn't show any colors.